# Why intercepter files are generator generation\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout\interceptor.php?

Tags: magento2, interceptor

I have Magento 2 with sample data and I came across this file

> generation\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout\interceptor.php.

The Interceptor file is generated only if any module wants to plugin (before/after/around) any method in given class . for example, this method `renderResult()` does not have any plugin like `beforeRenderResult/aroundRenderResult` . then Why interceptor file was generated ? Are there any other scenarios where interception file can be generated ?

```
public function renderResult(\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'renderResult');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::renderResult($response);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('renderResult', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can mark answers as accepted if they helped you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Plugins are inherited. `Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout` implements `Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface` and this interface have plugins

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface">
    <plugin name="result-builtin-cache" type="Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin"/>
    <plugin name="result-varnish-cache" type="Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin"/>
</type>
```